# create loop for video playing on jw player

Tags: video, media-player, jwplayer

I am using jw player to play a video on my website which I want to loop.  Can I do this?  I am pasting the code below but I don't think it will be of use to see the video since the player is loaded onto my website.  If someone can still answer the answer and tell me if/how I can loop the video I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/qkv6kzb.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/qkv6kzb.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    </header>
    <div>
        <script src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/JGjET8HV-DzNBF8a9.js"></script>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jw player API reference](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/jw7/), you can set `repeat` parameter to `true` from `jwplayer().setConfig()` :

```js
jwplayer().setConfig({
  repeat: true
});
```

```html
<div>
  <script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/players/JGjET8HV-DzNBF8a9.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Do you know if there is a way to make this loop run as soon as you get on the website, without having to click a control, and also, to make the loop seamless so that there is no break between the end and beginning of each iteration?  Thank you.

Comment: You have the `autostart` param to playback automatically

Comment: How to loop video without showing reload circle at the end of video?

Comment: @user1788736 I found that you can manually add `loop` attr to the video element. In this case, it should work like HTML looped video, but JWPlayer functionality is working well